# Reset a controller with another in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm a trainee java-dev and this is my first question here so please, don't judge me!

I have a Controller class which works with jsp files. The first jsp (userinput.jsp) has 3 text fields (lat, lon, radius) and 2 buttons (submit, apply default values). The second jsp is just an HTML table filled with data (depends on user input), and a reset button which should return you to the starter page (userinput.jsp) and delete all existing data. How should I do this?

Bonus question: If I try to refresh the page at the second state (html table), the browser generates a warning that says I'll lose all data and I shouldn't refresh. How can I get rid of this?

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class SpringBootController implements InitLogger {

    @GetMapping(value="/geohash")
    public String getUserInput(ModelMap model) {
        model.put("command", new Tuple());
        return "UserInput";
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/geohash", params="SubmitWithDefault")
    public String defaultUserInput(ModelMap model) {
        model.put("command", tupleFill (48.104564, 20.800041, 6) );
        return "UserInput";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/geohash", params="Submit")
    public String printHash(@ModelAttribute("user")Tuple tuple,ModelMap model) {
        GetData.setLat1(tuple.getFirstCoordinate());
        GetData.setLon1(tuple.getSecondCoordinate());
        GetData.setRad1(tuple.getRadius());

        LocationExecute.calculate();
        model.addAttribute("geoItemList", LocationExecute.getTupleList());
        model.addAttribute("listSize", LocationExecute.getTupleList().size());
        return "Geohash";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/geohash", params="reset", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView method() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:geohash");

    }
}
```

**userinput.jsp** - buttons

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" style="height:25px; width:100px"/> 
<input type="submit" name="SubmitWithDefault" value="Default Values" style="height:25px; width:100px">
```

**geohash.jsp** - (html table) reset button

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" style="height:30px; width:100px">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way:

geohash.jsp
(added form:form tags)

```
<form:form action="/geohash">
    <th> <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset" style="height:30px; width:100px"> </th>
    </form:form>
```

Controller
(changed method to post)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/geohash", params="reset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView method() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:geohash");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement PRG(Post -Redirect-Get)  design pattern in MVC to solve the issue.
 Please go through the below  for more information
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-prg-pattern-in-mvc-architecture/

So instead of returning view name redirect it so your problem will be solved, if you want some data to be sent to redirect method then use flashAttributes of spring